# Filter out results from sub query column

Tags: mysql

I have a query that attaching a value from a different query as sub select.

I need to filter the results (orders) based on the attached column (customer_name).

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    (
    SELECT name
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    id = orders.customer_id
) AS `customer_name`
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    `customer_name` LIKE '%smith%'
```

From some reason, this query not returning any result, although there is customer named smith.

**I can't** use `join` in order to join the `name`, this example is a simplification of my query, my original query requires to "attach" multiple values from the same table.

I'm getting `Unknown column 'customer_name' in 'where clause'`

Reproduction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f28834/2

Expected result is all the orders that belongs to customer with the name `smith`.

In the example orders 1,2,3

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: *"my original query requires to "attach" multiple values from the same table."* Your query will fail if multiple records match..

Comment: did you get any errors. if yes what? also `id = orders.customer_id` your this line may return multiple rows. use `limit 1`

Comment: *"your this line may return multiple rows. use limit 1"* @danish-khan-I simply adding `limit 1` is playing russian roulette  as SQL tables/resultsets are defined to be **orderless** by the ANSI/ISO SQL standards

Comment: @danish-khan-I, it is not an issue of multiple rows.

Comment: *"it is not an issue of multiple rows"* @felixmosh see mine first comment then we can stop guessing and provide you with real answers.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I've added

Comment: And the expected results? the link i have provided has a tool to create ascii text data tables.

Answer (score 2):

I've went around it, by searching by id with sub-query,

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT name FROM customers WHERE id = orders.customer_id) AS `customer_name`
FROM
    orders
where 
    customer_id in (select id from customers where name like '%smith%');
```

Answer (score 0):

use where condition inside the subquery

```sql
SELECT *, ( 
            SELECT name
            FROM customers
            WHERE id = orders.customer_id
          ) AS `customer_name`
FROM
    orders
WHERE 
   orders.customer_id IN ( 
                           SELECT id
                           FROM customers
                           WHERE customers.name like '%smith%'
                         )
```

Comment: It will not return the orders that belongs to customer with the name `smith`, its just will not add the name of the customer.

Comment: @felixmosh: Try this now.

Comment: It return all the orders, but this is the same direction I went, filtering by the `customer_id`, see my answer, it works

Comment: @felixmosh: it's a mistakenly updated the code. I updated my code now

Comment: @NishalK.R, now it throws an error cause the select returns multiple rows

Comment: @felixmosh: okay. I see my mistake that forgotten to add the apostrophe after the `%`. I updated the code again :(

Comment: @NishalK.R, not related to `%` your sub-query return several rows, check in the playground that I've attached.